# How to implement search functionality for Google Map Api V2 Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, search, maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I need to implement a search functionality for my Android Google Map Api V2 project and can't find any working example. I just need to enter a city name, press a "Search" button and then the map should move to the city and show a marker on it. Just like the Google Maps application does. Autocompletion should be nice though. I actully get to show the map, show some markers, etc, I just can't get to perform the search and see the results. Please help!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I just need to enter a city name, press a "Search" button and then
>   the map should move to the city and show a marker on it. Just like the
>   Google Maps application does.

So for that you have to make the functionality on Click of search in which you have to do as follows:

- The city name entered by the user Will be sent to the [google api](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=NewYork&sensor=true) - It
  will get back the lat-long to you.
- You will use that lat-long to add marker as well as,
- You will use that lat-long to animate the Gmaps Camara. That's it.
- In this way you are able to fullfill your above requirement.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, moving the map to a certain point is done by calling the `GoogleMap` object's `moveCamera()` method:

```
 GoogleMap map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

 LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.867, 151.206);

 map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
 map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 13));
```

Taken from [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/) example.

As you can see, you'll need the latitude and longitude coordinates for creating a `LatLng` object. I believe you can use place search from google to obtain those coordinates, using http-requests. Example:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/xml?query=restaurants+in+Sydney&sensor=true&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere
```

taken from [here](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search)

which should return JSON-data for you.

For autocomplete, see [this](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete) link

**Edit:** Wops, the place search would return xml, try using ...json?query=... instead