# Implementing Android Google Map Search functionality V2

Tags: android, google-places-api, android-maps-v2

[image]

I want to implement search for the country/state/city or nearby places in my android map Application, I know this question has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21663112/how-to-implement-search-functionality-for-google-map-api-v2-android) but thought to raise it once more as I'm still struggling to find any elegant solution here on SO.I've also referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192601/how-to-search-in-google-map-api-v2-android) post but after reading some comments I lost hope.So if anyone has implemented places api in android??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The straightforward way is to use the `Google Geocoding API`. You can access it with

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA

That will return you a `JSON` with the location data for that address including latitude and longitude. Here's some code snippets from what I've done:

```
               try{
                    JSONConnectorGet jget=new JSONConnectorGet(url);
                    returnval=jget.connectClient();
                    results=returnval.getJSONArray("results");
                    resultobj=results.getJSONObject(0);
                    System.out.println(resultobj.toString());
                    geometry=resultobj.getJSONObject("geometry");
                    location=geometry.getJSONObject("location");


                    lati=location.getDouble("lat");
                    longi=location.getDouble("lng");

                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                a=new LatLng(lati, longi);
```

Here `JSONConnectorGet` is a class I wrote that can be used to send a `HttpGet` request and receive back a `JSONObject`. `returnval` is a `JSONObject` I've declared. `url` is the URL given above with address replaced with whatever is searched.

Then you have to extract the `LatLng` from the `JSONObject`. The `JSONObjects` and `JSONArrays` I've used are declared outside the try-catch block. Now I have the Latitude and Longitude of my search place in `a`.

Now I simply move the camera to that location.

```
eventmap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(a, 3.0f));
```

You can add a marker at that `LatLng` as well if you want.